# How submit a bug fix to Ubuntu?

Tags: development, bug-reporting

I've submitted a 'papercut' bug to launchpad, that I think I can possibly have a go at fixing.

What is the process for obtaining the relevant source code (I'm not entirely sure where I'd find the code responsible) and then submitting the change back to Ubuntu?

Comment: the first thing to do is make sure you're running latest and ppa(if the developer of that project has a bleeding edge ppa) and make sure it's not already fixed and just hasn't been backported yet.  apt-get source packagename drops the source for the relevant package in the current directory.  this isn't an answer because i have no idea on submitting the change.  get up with @JorgeCastro - his profile says he helps out with this type of thing

Answer (score 6):

Main tool on Ubuntu/Launchpad to manage SW version controls and SW changes is Bazaar.
You can find a wiki [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=916132).

In summary, to submit a change you should:

- Install bazaar: `sudo apt-get install bzr`
- Generate a SSH key and register it to you launchpad user ID (see the wiki mentioned above);
- Look for the package you want to fix. As an example let's say the package is '*swtobefixed*'.
- Download the branch: `bzr pull lp:swtobefixed`
- Update the local code and test it on your machine
- Commit changes: `bzr commit -m "Revision 1 Comment"`
- Push the change to launchpad: `bzr push lp:swtobefixed`

Please consider packages works with permissions.
References:

- http://daniel.holba.ch/blog/2011/03/ubuntu-development-guide-fixing-a-bug-in-ubuntu/