# How to submit bug fixes on launchpad?

Tags: launchpad, bug-reporting, bazaar

I'm on Xubuntu, I fixed some bugs for some application that runs on ubuntu and debian, how to submit those bug fixes to launchpad? The dev team confirmed the bug but didn't assign anyone, I waited a week, so I assigned myself and fixed everything, what's next?

I've  seen this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73809/how-submit-a-bug-fix-to-ubuntu), but the  project i'm working on is big in size. So isn't it possible, to upload just 1 file from my computer to the launchpad repo, without having to download the whole thing and push the whole thing? I just want to add a file. less than 1 Kb.

And is it possible to fix the debian package from my Ubuntu? or do I have to have a debian for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use bzr, or aren't familiar with debian packaging, and updating the changelog, etc, you can simply generate a `diff` ( preferably with -u ) of the file you changed, and attach it to the bug report and tag it with the tag 'patch' and hopefully someone else will take care of applying it properly and uploading it.

If you are comfortable with updating the debian change log ( `dch -i` ), and applying any upstream changes in a quilt patch ( assuming the package in question uses quilt ), you can do that, build the new package, and then use `debdiff` to generate a full diff between the old and new package version, and attach that to the bug report.  Assuming it also affects debian, you should file a bug there and attach the diff there as well, and link the launchpad bug report to the debian one.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look to [here](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Working_with_Bazaar)

Launchpad repository is stored as a bazaar repository on Launchpad.

The only first time is needed to download all the stuff. Then only partial updates are done regarding your changes

EDIT: make use of offline local version of source code

1. init repo:

   > ```
   > bzr init-repo --trees myrepo
   > cd myrepo
   > ```
2. Copy your files into myrepo Directory
3. Edit and commit!

Comment: But I  already have the package on PC, I downloaded it using apt-get, is it possible to create a fake bazaar repo, and copy to it the files on my pc? you know what i mean?

Comment: @Fischer Are you trying to decrease internet usage?

Comment: yep if that's possible

Comment: @Fischer I think you might be more interested in psusi's answer.